# PHP > cURL > Overriding http method > Requests in sequence

Tags: php, curl

I'm going crazy trying to figure out whats happening to an easy piece of code.

I'll write less code as I can to focus the issue.

**Target**

Execute two or more cURL requests with the same handle but different options.

**cURL wrapper portion**

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->handle = curl_init();
}

public function execute(){
    $handle = $this->handle;
    # ... some default, not relevant, options ... #
    # Retrieve the http method
    $http_method = $this->http_method;
    # Set the method
    switch($http_method){
        case 'GET':
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
            break;
        case 'POST':
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            break;
        default:
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $http_method);
            break;
    }
    # Set the url
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
    # Retrieve the payload
    $payload = $this->payload;
    # Set the payload
    if(!empty($payload)){
        # Specify data to send
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    }
    # Execute the request
    $result = curl_exec($handle);
    # Reset the handle
    curl_reset($handle);
    # Update the handle
    $this->handle = $handle;
}
```

**Sample of use**

```
    # First
    $obj->setHttpMethod('post');
    $obj->setURL("someurl");
    $payload = array(
        'field' => 'value'
    );
    $obj->setPayload($payload);
    $result = $obj->execute();

    # Second
    $obj->setHttpMethod('get');
    $obj->setURL("anotherurl");
    $result = $obj->execute();
```

**Result**

Second is executed as a POST instead of GET.

**Conclusion**

Thanks in advance: I will love any suggestion.

Comment: Hi Bruno, which PHP version and SO?

Comment: Haven't tested, a guess... You should probably set your payload to `null`...

Comment: @Saitama as I imagined it was something stupid like I am. Thanks a lot: it solved ! The only concern is why curl_reset() is not resetting CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ?

Comment: @Saitama never mind: I understood. curl_reset cannot reset data stored on my object. Sorry and thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to post it as an answer:

The post fields are already retained when you do a POST request, and subsequently do a GET request.

Thus, changing the fields to `null`, would make `cUrl` do a `GET` request rather than `POST`.